# Wall guide for sit-stand desk to improve stability

Tags: furniture, desk

I have a sit-stand desk which moves 50cm vertically. It can be quite wobbly due to the weight of the desk top, and is easy to oscillate side-side or front-back. With static furniture, my response would be to secure it to the wall but that would prevent up-down movement.

Is there a solution that would allow me to attach the desk to the wall while still permitting vertical movement?

Specifics:

- Desk top is solid wood, 40mm thick. I am able to drill into it and attach brackets.
- It's not possible to attach any part of the base to the wall as the table top overhangs on all sides.
- The desk top is adjacent to walls on the rear and right-hand sides.
- The desk top is 15mm from the walls and can be moved further away but not closer due to skirting boards obstructing the base.
- There is space on the walls to mount 50cm guides

Comment: This probably would be considered a "shopping" question, and so off-topic here, but have you considered vertically mounting a pair of drawer slides? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I bought two 500mm linear rails that were originally designed for use in CNC machinery. I will attach one on the rear wall and one on the right wall, attaching the carriages to the desk top. The total cost was around £20, but searching for the term `linear rail` provides plenty of options.

[image]